# harish chandra for sl(2,C)

Tags: representation-theory

Is it true that each irreducible sl(2,$\mathbb{C}$)-module, $P(\lambda,\mu)$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$
  appears as the harish chandra module of some $(\pi_{\chi},V_{\chi})$
  And given $\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}$
  and $\mu\in\mathbb{C}$
  such that neither of $\lambda\pm\sqrt{\mu+1}$
  is an odd integer what is $\chi$

also any good references on this material? I'v only seen a cursory introduction in some course notes but can't find any good book on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in this, but you might probably be able to find something similar in Daniel Bump's Automorphic Forms and Representations. There is one section in Chapter 2 on Harish-Chandra's $\mathfrak{g}-K$ module. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I checked it out but it doesnt have what I need thanks though.